# Ant Design: defaultValue of <DatePicker/> component is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, ant-design-pro

I am creating a detail page where I want to display an editable deadline and for that, I am using `<DatePicker>` component of `Ant Design`. The problem is when I set `defaultValue={moment(deadline)}` it's not showing the date `deadline` variable is holding but instead, it is showing the current date.

```
<DatePicker
    showTime
    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
    placeholder="Set Deadline"
    defaultValue={moment(deadline)} //moment(deadline) returns valid moment date objcect
    onOk={(value, dateString) => {
        newDeadline = value._d;
        updateDeadline(newDeadline);
    }}
/>
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong please help me to find it out...

**UPDATE**

When I console the value of `deadline`, `typeof deadline`, `moment(deadline).toString()` all are returning data as expected.

When I use `value={moment(deadline)}` instead of `defaultValue={moment(deadline)}`, It's also working fine. 
One interesting thing, when I pass date string instead of `deadline` variable to `defaultValue`, It's working smoothly.

Comment: Please share the `deadline` variable.

Comment: It is holding a valid date `2018-12-20T07:37:50.886Z`, thanks for response

Comment: Is `DatePicker` wrapped into `getFieldDecorator`? Can you share the whole form?

Comment: No, It isn't wrapped into `getFieldDecorator`.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jj906womxw ...Working as expected, AntD version ?